# Possible memory error while running a query with several CTEs on Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I'm running a query with several CTEs and it is throwing the following error:

```
ERROR:  Assert
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   query->a_last_plan()->m_locus == LocusXNode - 
  query:     105350
  location:  <----->
  process:   padbmaster [pid=18065]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

My research shows that this corresponds to memory error, but it could be something else as well. So I resized the cluster I am running this query on and the disk space used now is below 2.5% and the CPU utilization is around 60%. But I'm still continuing to get this error.

Would anyone have any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Here's the partial `EXPLAIN` output of the query:

```
                  ->  XN Network  (cost=2217335550055.32..2217335550055.33 rows=5 width=68)
                        Send to leader
                        ->  XN Sort  (cost=2217335550055.32..2217335550055.33 rows=5 width=68)
                              Sort Key: event_no
                              ->  XN Subquery Scan derived_table1  (cost=1217335550055.02..1217335550055.26 rows=5 width=68)
                                    ->  XN Window  (cost=1217335550055.02..1217335550055.13 rows=5 width=52)
                                          Order: event_no
                                          ->  XN Sort  (cost=1217335550055.02..1217335550055.03 rows=5 width=52)
                                                Sort Key: event_no
                                                ->  XN Network  (cost=334239012.02..217335550054.96 rows=5 width=52)
                                                      Send to slice 0
                                                      ->  XN Subquery Scan events_agg_ring_users  (cost=334239012.02..217335550054.96 rows=5 width=52)
                                                            ->  XN Unique  (cost=334239012.02..217335550054.91 rows=5 width=36)
                                                                  ->  XN Append  (cost=334239012.02..217335550054.86 rows=5 width=36)
                                                                        ->  XN Network  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.04 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                              Distribute Round Robin
                                                                              ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.04 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                    ->  XN Subquery Scan email_data_ring_users  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.03 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                          ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.02 rows=1 width=21)
                                                                                                ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE  (cost=205997849.04..334239012.00 rows=1 width=21)
                                                                                                      Hash Cond: ("outer".mailer_method_enum = "inner".mailer_method_enum)
                                                                                                      ->  XN Hash IN Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=205997840.80..334239002.92 rows=66 width=25)
                                                                                                            Hash Cond: ("outer".user_id = "inner".user_id)
                                                                                                            ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021 e  (cost=0.00..123532147.20 rows=376721141 width=25)
                                                                                                                  Filter: ((sent_at <= '2021-04-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (sent_at >= '2021-04-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                                            ->  XN Hash  (cost=205997840.74..205997840.74 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                  ->  XN Subquery Scan users_in_ring  (cost=205997620.44..205997840.74 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                        ->  XN Unique  (cost=205997620.44..205997840.50 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                              InitPlan
                                                                                                                                ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_start_date  (cost=102998810.21..102998810.23 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                      InitPlan
                                                                                                                                        ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_end_date  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.21 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                              InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.19 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                      InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                        ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                                                              Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                                                                                                      ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021  (cost=0.00..102943456.00 rows=22138378 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                            Filter: (mailer_method_enum = $67)
                                                                                                                                              ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                                      ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                                ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_end_date  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.21 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                      InitPlan
                                                                                                                                        ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.19 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                              InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                                                      Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                                                                                              ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021  (cost=0.00..102943456.00 rows=22138378 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                    Filter: (mailer_method_enum = $71)
                                                                                                                                      ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                              ->  XN Seq Scan on premium_user_treatments  (cost=0.00..220.00 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                                    Filter: ((created_at >= $70) AND (created_at <= $73) AND ((reason = 38) OR (reason = 43) OR (reason = 40) OR (reason = 49) OR (reason = 51)))
                                                                                                      ->  XN Hash  (cost=8.24..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                            ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods "mm"  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                  Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                        ->  XN Network  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.04 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                              Distribute Round Robin
                                                                              ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.04 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                    ->  XN Subquery Scan email_data_ring_users  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.03 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                          ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.02 rows=1 width=21)
                                                                                                ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE  (cost=205997849.04..334239012.00 rows=1 width=21)
                                                                                                      Hash Cond: ("outer".mailer_method_enum = "inner".mailer_method_enum)
                                                                                                      ->  XN Hash IN Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=205997840.80..334239002.92 rows=66 width=25)
                                                                                                            Hash Cond: ("outer".user_id = "inner".user_id)
                                                                                                            ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021 e  (cost=0.00..123532147.20 rows=376721141 width=25)
                                                                                                                  Filter: ((sent_at <= '2021-04-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (sent_at >= '2021-04-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                                            ->  XN Hash  (cost=205997840.74..205997840.74 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                  ->  XN Subquery Scan users_in_ring  (cost=205997620.44..205997840.74 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                        ->  XN Unique  (cost=205997620.44..205997840.50 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                              InitPlan
                                                                                                                                ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_start_date  (cost=102998810.21..102998810.23 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                      InitPlan
                                                                                                                                        ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_end_date  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.21 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                              InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.19 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                      InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                        ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                                                              Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                                                                                                      ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021  (cost=0.00..102943456.00 rows=22138378 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                            Filter: (mailer_method_enum = $60)
                                                                                                                                              ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                                      ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                                ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_end_date  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.21 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                      InitPlan
                                                                                                                                        ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.19 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                              InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                                                      Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                                                                                              ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021  (cost=0.00..102943456.00 rows=22138378 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                    Filter: (mailer_method_enum = $64)
                                                                                                                                      ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                              ->  XN Seq Scan on premium_user_treatments  (cost=0.00..220.00 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                                    Filter: ((created_at >= $63) AND (created_at <= $66) AND ((reason = 38) OR (reason = 43) OR (reason = 40) OR (reason = 49) OR (reason = 51)))
                                                                                                      ->  XN Hash  (cost=8.24..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                            ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods "mm"  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                  Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                        ->  XN Network  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.04 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                  Distribute Round Robin
                                                                                  ->  XN Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 3"  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.04 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                        ->  XN Subquery Scan email_data_ring_users  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.03 rows=1 width=16)
                                                                                              ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=334239012.02..334239012.02 rows=1 width=21)
                                                                                                    ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE  (cost=205997849.04..334239012.00 rows=1 width=21)
                                                                                                          Hash Cond: ("outer".mailer_method_enum = "inner".mailer_method_enum)
                                                                                                          ->  XN Hash IN Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=205997840.80..334239002.92 rows=66 width=25)
                                                                                                                Hash Cond: ("outer".user_id = "inner".user_id)
                                                                                                                ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021 e  (cost=0.00..123532147.20 rows=376721141 width=25)
                                                                                                                      Filter: ((sent_at <= '2021-04-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (sent_at >= '2021-04-06 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                                                                                                ->  XN Hash  (cost=205997840.74..205997840.74 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                      ->  XN Subquery Scan users_in_ring  (cost=205997620.44..205997840.74 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                            ->  XN Unique  (cost=205997620.44..205997840.50 rows=24 width=4)
                                                                                                                                  InitPlan
                                                                                                                                    ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_start_date  (cost=102998810.21..102998810.23 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                          InitPlan
                                                                                                                                            ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_end_date  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.21 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                  InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                    ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.19 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                          InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                            ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                                                                  Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                                                                                                          ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021  (cost=0.00..102943456.00 rows=22138378 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                                Filter: (mailer_method_enum = $53)
                                                                                                                                                  ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                                          ->  XN Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
                                                                                                                                    ->  XN Subquery Scan ring_end_date  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.21 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                          InitPlan
                                                                                                                                            ->  XN Aggregate  (cost=102998810.19..102998810.19 rows=1 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                  InitPlan
                                                                                                                                                    ->  XN Seq Scan on mailer_methods  (cost=0.00..8.24 rows=1 width=4)
                                                                                                                                                          Filter: ((mailer_method)::text = 'claim_papers_blast'::text)
                                                                                                                                                  ->  XN Seq Scan on email_funnel_2021  (cost=0.00..102943456.00 rows=22138378 width=8)
                                                                                                                                                        Filter: (mailer_method_enum = $57)
```

Comment: Why do you say that this corresponds to a memory error?  I've seen this error with non-memory related query issues.  Not saying it isn't but there are other possible causes (like data type mismatches in a UNION and RS bug).  Can you post the explain plan for the query?  This can give some idea as to what is happening during the query.

Comment: My research showed that this happens coz of memory error. Thanks for letting me know that there may be other causes for this. I will post an explain on the query shortly.

Comment: I've added a partial output of `EXPLAIN`. Couldn't paste the entire output as I was running out of word limit allowed by StackOverflow.

Comment: Does this query run a long time before it errors out?

Comment: It runs for about a minute (at times less) before it errors out.

Comment: So not sure you're going to like this answer - I think you need to isolate the portion of the SQL that is throwing the error.  This query is big enough that RS is decomposing it into several queries and combining the results.  One way an assert error happens in when these parts are brought back together and the data types mismatch (usually due to implicit casts).  Determining where in the query the error comes from can lead to fixes like adding explicit casts to ensure types match.  But this is only one possible cause.